# SharePoint 2010 Web Analytics Master Page Issue

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-analytics

Immeditely after clicking on the "Site Web Analytics reports" of any site within my sharepoint 2010 environment I reveive the following.
"Error 
An unexpected error has occurred. 
Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation. 
Correlation ID: f5432f95-b187-49a5-88e0-99a8dcf975f2 
Date and Time: 12/2/2013 4:01:53 PM 
Go back to site"

I searched the ULS logs and found http://sdrv.ms/19dCCRQ 
I have Performed the steps located here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepoint_strategery/archive/2012/03/16/troubleshooting-sharepoint-2010-web-analytics.aspx
Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change the masterpage to the default masterpage?
I am running into the same problem. 
To test my theory without touching your original this is what I did:

1. Create a sub-site
2. Then change the masterpage on the sub-site using the _layouts/ChangeSiteMasterpage.aspx and selected the v4.masterpage for both the Site masterpage and the System Masterpage. 
   Once I did that, the web analytics page began to render like it should.

I hope this helps.